# Referencing error with a variable when trying to render an EJS file to display a table of information from mySQL database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, undefined, ejs

Very new to everything so might be a silly query but I receive this error when I try to click on a webpage that should show a table of data from my mysql database but I receive this error:

```
  ReferenceError: C:\webproject\views\readcontactinfo.ejs:31
        29|           <th>Message</th>
        30|         </tr>
     >> 31|         <% if( contactdata && contactdata.length > 0) { %>
        32|             <% contactdata.forEach(function(data) { %>
        33|             <tr>
        34|                 <td><%=data.id %></td>

        contactdata is not defined
```

In my server-side script I have:

```
app.get('/readcontactinfo', function(req, res) {
      contactpool.query("SELECT id, name, email, contactno, message FROM info", function (err,    result)     

      { if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      res.render('readcontactinfo', {title: 'xyz', contactdata: result});
      });
      });
```

Which should pass the data to my template page but its not being received correctly. This is my template:

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
          <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Contact No</th>
          <th>Message</th>
          </tr>
          <% if( contactdata && contactdata.length > 0) { %>
          <% contactdata.forEach(function(data) { %>
          <tr>
          <td><%=data.id %></td>
          <td><%=data.name %></td>
          <td><%=data.email %></td>
          <td><%=data.contactno %></td>
          <td><%=data.message %></td>
          </tr>
          <%  }); %>
          <% } else { %>
          <tr>
          <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
          </tr>
          <% } %>
          </table>
```

I've made sure the directory structure is correct, the variable is correctly spelled in both the server-side & EJS code, I have cleared my cache & restarted server & also tried this code as my template:

```
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
        <%=if(userData.length!=0){ var i=1; userData.forEach(function(data) { %>
        <tr>
        <td><%=data.id %></td>
        <td><%=data.name %></td>
        <td><%=data.email %></td>
        <td><%=data.contactno %></td>
        <td><%=data.message %></td>
        </tr>
        <% i++;  }) %><% } else { %>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
        </table>
```

I just keep getting the same error over and over.

Comment: Try working with `title` only(comment out other code), if that works, then you should be able to display table of data.